# How can I change the "sites/default" into "web/sites/subsite" on the new location?

Tags: files

I have moved the content (files and database) of my "traditional" site (no composer, single site, using sites/default/files folder ) to a subsite on a multi-site that is created using composer. The images do not show, because the new site is still using part of the old path.

The path to images used is

- https://subsite.domain.be/sites/default/files/201505/image.jpg

while it should be:

- https://subsite.domain.be/web/sites/subsite/files/201505/image.jpg

Path in admin/config/media/file-system on the subsite seems correct:

- Public file system path : sites/subsite/files
- Public file base URL : https://subsite.domain.be/web/sites/subsite/files

In the source code of some of the body fields holding the images, I see the ancient URLs of subsite.drupalgardens.com ?!? (does no longer exist, while these images did show up on the traditional site that uses default/files)

Why are the images addressed wrong ?
How can I change the "sites/default"  (or the drupalgardens-link)  into "web/sites/subsite" on the new location ?
Or what could/should I have done before importing the database ? (I can start over, no problem)

Comment: I'm confused by the `/web/` part in your links. Maybe your base URL is misconfigured to include it and it shouldn't? Otherwise maybe your Public file system path should include it? Do you actually see your images if you visit them with the /web in links?

Comment: When I  visit the URL https://subsite.domain.be/web/sites/subsite/files/201505/image.jpg (substituting the value of subsite with the actual name) I can see the image. When I rightclick (copy URL) on the placeholder of the image on a webpage I get https://subsite.domain.be/sites/default/files/201505/image.jpg and when I use this link, the object is not found.

Comment: The /web/ part was automatically added when I created the website using composer with the recommended-project template

Comment: This is a common problem with hosting configuration differences. Yes, the /web is a regular part of the Drupal installation, nothing wrong there. There are too many different combinations/reasons that may be causing this, but I'd first check that your new site has /web included in the path, so nothing needs to be done with your "static" site, you have to "fix" the new site to not include /web in the path. Do other sites in your multisite also have /web? Your server needs to point to the /web folder as the host root, check your vhost config, Drupal .htaccess and settings.php WRT to that.

Comment: Yes, the new subsite has /web included in the path (as shown on the admin/config/media/file-system page) and other subsites on this multi have, too. Those others did not have inline images in body-fields. What should I look for in .htaccess or settings.php ?

Comment: `RewriteBase /web`. If you have access to your server configuration (you usually don't on a shared host) point your vhost to /web/ folder instead of the folder above. That would fix all your sites not to have /web in paths. If you don't have access to server config then try the RewriteBase in .htaccess.

Comment: No effect: I added this RewriteBase /web and flushed caches in all 3 sites. It seems to have no effect at all.  I see no more or less images than without it.